# HTML Purifier filter inbound or outbound or both?

Tags: php, mysql, htmlpurifier

I've just started using HTML Purifier http://htmlpurifier.org to filter content from a WYSIWYG editor. The content will be displayed back to the user or other users in the same group. There are other groups on the system and data integrity is very important.

I'm using PHP and the content is stored in a MySQL database.

HTML Purifier uses plenty of processor power so I'd like to only use it on the inbound content and display outbound content straight from the database without any filters. It sounds simple that it's been filtered so it should be safe, but I'm not 100% sure, is it safe?

Allowed list for inbound
'p[style],strong,em,u,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,ol,ul,span[style],div[style],br,ins,del'

EDIT: I found that the site suggests to do this at http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-slow.html but I would like a few opinions here because of the high importance.

Comment: Have a look at OWASP's [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize your input when you're sending it to the database, or you'll have big trouble with a few pageviews/second since this is a CPU intensive step.

BUT, you have to make sure every line in your database is sanitized, or you'll expose yourself to XSS someday (check every request that edits or add an entry, and think about existing lines in your database).

Small tip : if you can afford the space, store the sanitized and the not-sanitized input. If, one day, you have to change something in your parameters or HTMLPurifier has a major 0-day, you'll be able to update your entire table. But, be very cautious to the effects if you do this one day ;)

Edit : be sure what you're doing by allowing style, or allow only a fews CSS styles...

Comment: Thanks Ugo, I'm only using the purifier on the wysiwyg entered content. Everything else will use a standard php filter to rigorously strip and validate to plain text. What would you suggest to allow within the style attribute?

Comment: Nothing more than color, font-size, font-weight, background-color, text-align and so on. Avoid things like position, top, left, margin...